# illegal access to loading collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I know there are many answers for this.But am not getting want is missing from me.I have tried a lot but don't find what am missing.Getting `'illegal access to loading collection '`

Even any suggesstions wil be appricated

nhibernate .hbm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="EMSModels" assembly="EMSModels" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Reimbursement" table="Reimbursement">
    <id name="ID" column="ReimbursementID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="EmployeeID" type="int" />
    <property name="SubmissionDate" type="DateTime" />
    <property name="Description" type="string" length="500" />
     <property name="IsActive" type="bool" />
    <property name="IsDeleted" type="bool" />
    <many-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" column="EmployeeID" insert="false" update="false"/>
    <bag name="ReimbursementDetails"  cascade="all" inverse="true">
      <key column="ReimbursementID"></key>
      <one-to-many class="ReimbursementDetails"/>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Model

```
public class Reimbursement
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    // public virtual ReimbursementDetails ReimbursementDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ReimbursementDetails> ReimbursementDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual string Custom_SubmissionDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime date = SubmissionDate;
            return date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lazy loaded collection in your entity, and at the moment at which you want to load the collection, your NHibernate Session is closed.

Comment: what should i do than.Dont know how to work it around?

Comment: Keep your session open or load the collection eagerly instead of lazy.